# Magento products not visible via REST api addition

Tags: web-services, api, magento, rest

I'm currently running into the problem that I am using a webservice system to load products into magento.

I'm using the REST api in conjunction with Oauth to create products and assign a category. It works and when I go to the admin I can see the products as well as see they are properly assigned to the correct category. When I open the category management in the management console i can see i have (example: 106) items assigned in the category.

*However*, the problem is: It does not show in the site.. even with refreshing anything that is cache or index.

When I open up the management console and open 1 article and save it without changing any other property and then Save it. I can suddenly see the item in the front end webshop...

I'm lost to why this occurs.. also for 19k product updates it is becoming a bit of an annoying bit of work to update this amount of products since any bulk update method does not do the same as editing just 1 product at a time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have discovered the answer myself. Thought it might be nice to list it here as well.

In the 'rights' tab i added all the accessrights for the user using the api. This allowed me to read products etc. Very stupid mistake but somehow I overlooked this at first.

IF you'd expect security errors.. you wont get any. just empty lists and null responses.